# libgazebo_player not found

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have been using player/stage together with control code in c++ for a while and want to upgrade to player/gazebo. To get started I have followed the [user guide](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started__interfaces__player.html).

When I run "gazebo pioneer2dx.world" gazebo starts up fine, but when I run "player gazebo.cfg" I get the following error messages:

```
error   : Failed to load plugin libgazebo_player.
error   : libtool reports error: file not found
error   : plugin search path: /home/ulrik/Work/thirdparty/gazebo_source/test:.:/usr/local/lib/
error   : failed to load plugin: libgazebo_player
error   : failed to parse config file gazebo.cfg driver blocks
```

Both player (version 3.1.0) and gazebo (version 1.9) are installed in /usr/local and libgazebo_player.so is located in /usr/local/lib. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to /usr/local/lib.
I installed player before gazebo and gazebo found player when installed. (No warnings or errors when running cmake.)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thanks,
Ulrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4025/libgazebo_player-not-found/) by [Ulrik](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/453/ulrik/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-08-02**:
What does `ldd /usr/local/lib/libgazebo_player.so | grep "not found"` give you?  Any unresolved library references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A colleague of mine managed to solve the problem. By running

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libgazebo_player.so player my_file.cfg
```

we got an error message that was kind of wierd but included "gazebo" and "util". So by adding "gazebo_util" to to "target_link_libraries" in gazebo/interfaces/player/CMakeList.txt and build again all works fine. (He got the idea from a similar problem described here: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.playerstage.user/12204)

I guess

```
ldd /usr/local/lib/libgazebo_player.so | grep "not found"
```

as garkey proposed above would have pointed us in the same direction.

Anyway, I guess an update is needed for cmake to automatically include gazebo_util.

---

Originally posted by [Ulrik](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/453/ulrik/) with karma: 16 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-08-08**:
Here is a pull request to fix this problem: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/649/added-missing-lib-to-player-client-library/diff